# Group BY product using MAX(price) or MAX(date) according to time interval

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, max, min

I've been searching for answers for 2 day and still nothing. Please, help me.

I have a database with products, product's prices and the date when this prices were registered:

```
product_id | price | date
-------------------------
    1      | 8.95  | 2012-12-01
    2      | 3.40  | 2012-12-01
    1      | 9.05  | 2012-12-19
    3      | 2.34  | 2012-12-24
    3      | 2.15  | 2012-12-01
    1      | 8.80  | 2012-12-19
    1      | 8.99  | 2012-12-02
    2      | 3.45  | 2012-12-02
```

Observe that is possible to have different price values for a product on the same day (rows 3 and 6). This is because there are many suppliers for a single product. There is a supplier column on database too, but I found it irrelevant for the solution. You can add it to the solution if I'm wrong.

Basically what I want is to write a query that returns two combined sets of data, as follow:

- First set is made by minimum price of products inserted in the last month. As today is jan, 15, query should read rows 3, 4 and 6, apply the minimum price, and return only rows 4 and 6, both with minimum price for that product on the last month.
- Second set is made by last products inserted, with no price registered on last month. i.e, for products not shown in the first set, query should search for the last inserted ones.

I hope that is clear. Ask me more if it isn't.

The query result for this database should be:

```
product_id | price | date
-------------------------
    1      | 8.80  | 2012-12-19 <-Min price for product 1 on last month
    3      | 2.34  | 2012-12-24 <-Min price for product 3 on last month
    2      | 3.45  | 2012-12-02 <-No reg for product 2 on last month, show last reg.
```

I've tried everything: UNION, (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MIN(price), MAX(date) etc, etc. Nothing works. I don't know where to search now, please help me.

Comment: It seems that (the first part of) this question gets asked every 5 minutes or so in this forum (if that's the right word). Try reading a few adjacent threads.

Comment: Yes, first part is not hard, I can write it using GROUP BY, MIN and setting time interval. But when I try to combine both, I never get the expected result.

Comment: Try saving your first query in a temp table then take the set difference using `MINUS` between the original table and the temp table. The union temp table and the set difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(SELECT product_id, MIN(price), date
FROM products
WHERE date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH > NOW()
GROUP BY product_id)
UNION
(SELECT product_id, price, MAX(date)
FROM products
WHERE product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id
    FROM products
    WHERE date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH > NOW()
    GROUP BY product_id)
GROUP BY product_id)
```

This should work but I'm not sure it's the most optimized way to do it.

Comment: Should be better than my solution in abov, but i guess you do not condition "date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH < NOW() AND" in 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into several sub-queries:

- Products with prices in the last month, min price

  - join in date for that price

UNION

- Products with no-prices in the last month, max date

  - join in price on that date

### SQL Fiddle

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f7f0/26)

### Query

```
SELECT MINPRICE.product_id, P.date, MINPRICE.price
    FROM
    (
        -- Min price in last 31 days
        SELECT product_id, MIN(price) AS price
            FROM Prices
            WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) < 31
            GROUP BY product_id
    ) MINPRICE
    -- Join in to get the date that the price occured on
    INNER JOIN Prices P ON
        P.product_id = MINPRICE.product_id
        AND
        P.price = MINPRICE.price
UNION
SELECT MAXDATE.product_id, MAXDATE.date, P.price
    FROM
    (
        -- Product with no price in last 31 days - get most recent date
        SELECT product_id, MAX(date) AS date
            FROM Prices
            WHERE product_id NOT IN
            (
                SELECT product_id
                    FROM Prices
                    WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) < 31
            )
    ) MAXDATE
    -- join in price on that date
    INNER JOIN Prices P ON
        P.product_id = MAXDATE.product_id
        AND
        P.date = MAXDATE.date
```

Comment: I don't know how to select product with no prices in the last month, but that is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

something like this will do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT b.product_id, IF (c.min IS NULL,(SELECT ROUND(e.price,2) FROM products AS e WHERE e.product_id = b.product_id ORDER BY e.date DESC LIMIT 1 ),c.min) AS min, IF (c.date IS NULL,(SELECT f.date FROM products AS f WHERE f.product_id = b.product_id ORDER BY f.date DESC LIMIT 1 ),c.date) AS date, IF(c.min IS NULL,'<-No reg for product 2 on last month, show last reg.','<-Min price for product 1 on last month') as text FROM products AS b
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT a.product_id, round(MIN(a.price),2) AS min, a.date FROM products AS a WHERE a.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURDATE() GROUP BY a.product_id) AS c 
        ON (b.product_id = c.product_id)
    ) AS d
    ORDER BY d.text, d.product_id
```

Gives output:

```
product_id|min|date|text
1|8.80|2012-12-19|<-Min price for product 1 on last month
3|2.34|2012-12-24|<-Min price for product 1 on last month
2|3.45|2012-12-02|<-No reg for product 2 on last month, show last reg.
```

Comment: round is needed because i defined price as FLOAT

Answer (score -1):

Not that I tested but you can try...

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC)
  as tmp GROUP BY product_id) t1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT * FROM table WHERE date => CURDATE() ORDER BY price)
  as tmp2 GROUP BY product_id) t2
ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Comment: This query won't even run since `*` isn't in the `group by` clause.

Comment: You can only select the columns you've grouped by. Try running `select * from any_table group by column_in_any_table`.

Comment: @fo_x86 Nope. It works as of mysql v5.5.8. For other version I don't know.

Comment: Ha, interesting...maybe its an oracle thing...sry.